# CollectionViewSource and Linq

Tags: wpf, collectionviewsource

What is the easiest way to find an item in CollectionViewSource? I can't seem to find a linq friendly property. I would like to do something like MyCollectionViewSource.View.Where(x=>x...)

Cheers,
Berryl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to cast src.Source to whatever collection you bound it to.  For example, if your CollectionViewSource's Source is an IEnumerable<Int32> you would do this:

```
(MyCollectionViewSource.Source as IEnumerable<Int32>).Where(s => s < 2);
```